# .htaccess - How to hide the internal directory used by subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess, directory, subdomain, hide, internal

I installed a small FTP space for my classmates which allows them to upload school related documents to my server. After the files have been uploaded, they can be easily accessed via a subdomain i.e. ftp.mydomain.com

Everything is working fine, the files can be downloaded and everything works properly.
There are two things which still annoy me though:

- If you enter ftp.mydomain.com you see **Index of /my_internal_directory** instead of something like **Index of /**
- Once you enter a sub-directory and click the *Parent Directory* link it will redirect you to ftp.mydomain.com/my_internal_directory/ as well

Is there any way to hide my_internal_directory ?

This is the content of my .htaccess file so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ftp\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_internal_directory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_internal_directory/$1 [L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the . in your domain in the first RewriteCond pattern: ftp\.mydomain\.com

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I've edited my .htaccess file. But do you also have an idea of how to fix my major problem with that rule?

Comment: Sorry, no.  What you've done so far looks fine to me - is there maybe an issue with this being FTP and .htaccess is for HTTP requests?

Comment: I don't think so, as I soft-linked the directory used by the FTP to be accessible via Apache/HTTP. Unfortunately that link is visible to the users as well. What I would like to accomplish is to somehow hide it via htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using linux server then you can remove read permission for folder `my_internal_directory`

If not resolve, try to add:
`Options -Indexes`
on top of the file.

If still doesnt resolve please post your .htaccess file... :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it is not what I'd like to achieve, as it's meant to be a public FTP. I've created a sample subdomain: http://sample.betamaster.us/. When entering it, you see "Index of /home/sample", I'd like to see them "Index of /" though...